# C#: Order of execution of operands in an IF statement

Tags: c#

I came across some statements while surfing the .net source:

```
If( null != name)
If( false == check())
```

what is the difference between (name != null) and (Check() == false) statements from the above statements?

Can any one get me clear of this? Please.

Comment: I read the question wrong.. oops. I don't think there is a difference. Except that the order of comparison is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this style comes with C/C++ background, where the operator `=` which can also be used inside if statement, which could be used for comparison as well as assignment.

The statement 
`if( null != name)` is same as `if(name != null)`, so as the other statement

To safeguard from mistakenly assigning the value to the left hand side, this style of check is used in C/C++,

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find it right now.

Code with the constant first is usually written by developers with an (old) background in C, where you might write this:

```
if (NULL == x)
```

instead of this:

```
if (x == NULL)
```

just in case you made a typo like this:

```
if (x = NULL) // Valid, but doesn't do what you want.
```

In *most* cases in C#, you don't need to do this - because the condition in an `if` statement has to be convertible to `bool`.

It *would* make a difference when you're comparing to a Boolean constant:

```
if ((Check() = false) // Eek!
```

... which is one reason to just write:

```
if (!Check())
```

Basically, putting the variable first is generally more readable - and in C# the reason for putting the constant first is almost never applicable anyway. (Modern C and C++ compilers will usually give you a warning anyway, so it's no longer a great idea in those languages either, as far as I'm aware...)

In terms of the order of evaluation, there is a *theoretical* difference in that the left-hand operand *will* be evaluated before the right-hand operand... but as the constants `null` and `false` don't have any side-effects, there's no *real* difference.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [Coding Horror Yoda Conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html)

> Using if(constant == variable) instead of if(variable == constant),
>   like if(4 == foo). Because it's like saying "if blue is the sky" or
>   "if tall is the man".

Answer (score 0):

The odd reversal looks like it was written by a C/C++ programmer... basically, in C/C++, if you accidentally type:

```
if(name = null)
```

instead of

```
if(name == null)
```

then that *compiles* and changes the value to null when invoked. A C/C++ habit to avoid this mistake is to use a constant such as `null` / `false` ***always on the left***. This is because you can't reassign a constant, so it generates a compiler error if you use `=` instead of `==`. In C# it (`if(a = null)`) doesn't usually compile, so that is not a concern.

There is no difference re the position here - both sides are evaluated. Idiomatic C# for this would be simply:

```
if(name != null) ...
if(!check()) ...
```